# Is there a service that allows to access multiple API's using unified interface and one login?

Tags: web-services, api, catalog

Some time ago I was browsing the web, when I found a service that allowed to access multiple API's using single, unified interface and single login.

I remember that I browsed the catalog of API's and check OCR services to see what features they offer.

I don't remember if it was a free service or paid one. I didn't bookmark it and now I can't find it. I have found only [API's catalog on Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory).

Is anyone knows the name of this service?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after getting one vote down I decided to google more. No results. I reviewed bookmarks and... bingo!

It's called mashape.com and what I have had in mind was this [catalogue](https://market.mashape.com/explore).

*Disclaimer: I have no connection to this service. I just liked the idea.*

Edit:

I have [just found](https://dzone.com/articles/api-stack-apisio-and-apisguru-need-you-to-create-a) API search:
[{API}Search](http://apis.io/).
It does not allow to access mutiple API's using single credentials, but might be usefull for API's discovery.